# Error: C2280 Creating a vector of unique_ptr to Class

Tags: pointers, c++11, vector, game-engine, copy-constructor

It seems that when using a unique_ptr in `vector<unique_ptr<UserInterface>>` I get an error stating:

`Error  1   error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<UserInterface,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function  c:\pr...ude\xmemory0    593 1   Win32Project1`

Seemingly, no configuration allows me to store [smart] pointers to the UserInterface class, which has a  simple structure:

```
#define InterfaceContruct vector<unique_ptr<UserInterface>>

class UserInterfaceMgmt
{
public:
    UserInterfaceMgmt();
    ~UserInterfaceMgmt();

    InterfaceContruct Interface;

    void AddUIElement();
    void RemoveUIElement();
    void DrawInterface();
    void MoveElement();
private:
};
```

Even if no function is called, the error shows up (`InterfaceContruct Interface;` is instantiated) I tried putting the copy constructor in `private` but it persists.

The `.cpp` file is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "UserInterfaceMgmt.h"

UserInterfaceMgmt::UserInterfaceMgmt()
{
}

UserInterfaceMgmt::~UserInterfaceMgmt()
{
}

void UserInterfaceMgmt::DrawInterface(){
    for (UINT i = 0; i < Interface.size(); i++)
    {
        Interface[i]->Draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the instantiation backtrace for that error message?

Comment: How does your 'UserInterface' class look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector` (and most other containers in `std::`) require the value type to be copy-constructible. `std::unique_ptr` isn't copy constructible. Use `std::shared_ptr` or any other copy constructible types / pointers.

The clue is to look for `attempting to reference a deleted function`. This means there is some method which `= delete` has been used with. For instance:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(const Foo & rhs) = delete; // A deleted function
}
```

Comment: I see. That works; 'was so bent on making it work, I "knew" I could fly. I knew that unique_ptr<> deletes the copy-constructor, but tried to throw cleverness at it.

Comment: I'm going to test a basic configuration and come back to mark as answer.

Comment: @RashidEllis: You should not use `#define InterfaceContruct vector<unique_ptr<UserInterface>>`, but `typedef vector<unique_ptr<UserInterface>> InterfaceContruct` or the new C++11 way `using InterfaceContruct = vector<unique_ptr<UserInterface>>`.

Comment: for `using InterfaceContruct = vector<shared_ptr<UserInterface>>;` is there a difference in how the compiler is handling these?

Comment: It works! Thanks again(I did a look up on the processor definitions and it looks like `#define` is a blind definition; It was switched to a `using...` C++11 type)